# ubuntu desktop freezes whenever it is connceted to internet through wifi adapter

Tags: networking, freeze

I created a file server a few days ago in my Ubuntu desktop. I used a small Wi-Fi adapter device to connect it to the internet. The device was working fine but after I left the computer on for 1 complete day connected to the internet through the same device and tried to use the computer next day, it started freezing whenever the Wi-Fi adapter was connected to it. I even tried connecting another Wi-Fi adapter to the Ubuntu desktop and it didn't freeze. The computer freezes only when it is connected to the internet through that specific Wi-Fi adapter. Can you tell me what the problem is and how can I solve this?